# Let $X$ denote the smaller of the numbers on the drawn balls and $Y$ the larger. Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$

Tags: probability

An urn contains four balls; two of the balls are numbered whith a 1, and the other two are numbered with a 2. Two balls are drawn from the urn without replacement. Let $X$ denote the smaller of the numbers on the drawn balls and $Y$ the larger.

(left posible cases and right ($X$,$Y$) )

$(1,2)\rightarrow (1,2) $

$(1,2)\rightarrow (1,2) $

$(1,1)\rightarrow (1,1) $

$(2,1)\rightarrow (1,2) $

$(2,1)\rightarrow (1,2) $

$(2,2)\rightarrow (2,2) $

(a) Find the joint density of $X$ and $Y$

$$\begin{array}{c|cc|c}
x/y & 1& 2 & f_X(x)\\
\hline
\\ 1& 1/6 & 4/6& 5/6
\\ 2& 0 & 1/6 & 1/6
\\
\hline
\\ f_Y(y) & 1/6 & 5/6 &
\end{array}
$$

(b) Find the marginal distribution of $Y$

$f_Y(1)=\frac{1}{6}$ for $y=1$

$f_Y(2)=\frac{5}{6}$ for $y=2$

(c) Find the $cov[X,Y]$

$E[XY]=(1)(1)(\frac{1}{6})+(2)(1)(\frac{4}{6})+(2)(2)(\frac{1}{6})=\frac{13}{6}$

$E[X]=(1)(\frac{5}{6})+(2)(\frac{1}{6})=\frac{7}{6}$

$E[Y]=(1)(\frac{1}{6})+(2)(\frac{5}{6})=\frac{11}{6}$

$cov[X,Y]=\frac{1}{36}$

Comment: A question? :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen    I want to know if I have any mistake :)

Comment: @AndréNicolas    Yes :s, I did the respective correction Thanks you so much :)

Comment: Now It's OK (correction 1/36) Thanks

Comment: Everything is OK now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I see is that to get $Y=1$ you need to draw both $1$'s, probability $\frac 12\cdot \frac 13=\frac 16$  This forces $X=1$  Similarly, you get $X=2$ with probability $\frac 16$ and force $Y=2$.  Otherwise $X=1, Y=2$ with probability $\frac 23$.